# style binding with forloop using angular 11 reactive forms

Tags: angular

i have fetched some datas from backend need to use those value in style binding for apply width. but its not working i couldnt found the right solutions. here is my code follows..

in component.html file

```
<div class="radio-group">
                  <label class="container poll-done" *ngFor="let item of pollQuestion?.CM_Poll_Options;let i=index;let val of percentage;"
                    > {{item.pollOption}}
                    <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="pollOption" value="{{item.id}}" formControlName="pollOption"/>
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    <small>{{val.percentageValue | number}}</small>
                    <div [style.width]="{{val.percentageValue | number}}"><b>{{val.percentageValue | number}}</b></div>
                  </label>
                  
                </div>
```

I have used two loop to display the data. kindly suggest the better way to do dynamic style binding

Answer (score 0):

Maybe left the unit of width?
There is only a number in val.percentageValue and width needs a unit like %, px, rem, etc.
Try something like this:
[style.width]="{{val.percentageValue | number}}%"

Comment: its not working....cant able to use interpolation in binding

Answer (score 0):

Its working for me

```
<span [style.width]="data.percentageValue + '%' ">{{data.choice}}</span>
```